# C# Setter behavior difference in interface and interface with inheritance

Tags: c#, setter

I am currently learning C# and I have observed behavior that I cannot explain when I was playing around.

Given this interface:

```
using System;

namespace LearnInterfaces
{
  interface IAutomobile
  {
    string LicensePlate { get; }
    double Speed { get; }
    int Wheels { get; }
    void Honk();
  }
}
```

I implement the class like so :

```
using System;

namespace LearnInterfaces
{
  class Sedan : IAutomobile
  {
    public Sedan(double speed, int wheels){
      this.Speed = speed;
      this.LicensePlate = Tools.GenerateLicensePlate();
      this.Wheels = wheels;
    }

    public string LicensePlate
    { get; }

    public double Speed
    { get; }

    public int Wheels
    { get; }

    publc void Honk(){.....};
    
  }
}
```

This is fine, and I can instantiate the Sedan in my main program.

However, when it comes to inheritance + interface, this behavior is no longer ok:

If I decided to add a new base class and make `Sedan` inherit from it:

```
class Vehicle
{
    public string LicensePlate
    { get; }

    public double Speed
    { get; }

    public int Wheels
    { get; }

    
    public void Honk()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("HONK!");
    }

}
```

Changed so that Sedan inherit from it:

```
  class Sedan : Vehicle, IAutomobile
  {
    public Sedan(double speed)
    {
      Speed = speed;
      LicensePlate = Tools.GenerateLicensePlate();
      Wheels = 4;
    }
    
  }
```

Now if I try to instantiate from my main program, I get `Property or indexer 'Vehicle.Speed' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`. The same error happens for every property in the class.

Why do I need a setter now when I make Sedan inherit from a base class? In my understanding, the Sedan will also inherit the getter; so instantiate it with constructor should be ok (just like previous example where it simply implements the interface).

Comment: The error message mentions `SpeedUp`, not `Speed`. Where is `SpeedUp` in your posted code?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code - it will help you asking questions and narrow problems down, possibly solving yourself. In case of this question you would notice that there is no need for an interface at all and all you needed as sample is roughly `Base {public {Speed {get}}}  Derived :Base { Base {Speed = 1}}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I need a setter now?

Because a `get`-only auto-property can only be assigned in the constructor *of the enclosing class*.

From the [language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#readonly-fields):

> Just like a readonly field, a getter-only auto-property can also be assigned to in the body of a constructor of the enclosing class. Such an assignment assigns directly to the readonly backing field of the property.

So essentially you are assigning to the backing field of the property, which is `readonly`. If you read about the [behaviour of `readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#readonly-fields), the reason for this restriction is even clearer:

> Direct assignments to readonly fields can only occur as part of that declaration or in an instance constructor or static constructor **in the same class**.

`Sedan` is not the enclosing class of `LicensePlate`, `Speed` and `Wheels` etc, so you can't set them in `Sedan`'s constructor.

Comment: So can I understand it as: "child classes(unless they have their own properties), are never the enclosing classes of properties that they inherente from parents)?

Comment: The "enclosing class" of a member means "the class in which that member is declared", so yes that's right. @AngryOtter

Comment: thank you. I was looking at the wrong place then. I was reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties and could not find the answer I wanted, then decided to ask here

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your constraints and what you are trying to achieve. However the problem is because your base class has get only properties. These properties can only be set in the constructor, which does not include derived constructors. The easiest (may not be the best) way to achieve this is with [protected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected) setters on your base class which makes these properties mutable for derived classes. The alternative is have constructor on your base class

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class
> instances.

```
public string LicensePlate { get; protected set; }
public double Speed { get; protected set; }
public int Wheels { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: This doesn't sit well with me because that means those properties are mutable. And mutable objects are painful in the long-term. If we're talking about C# 9 then how about `protected init` instead?

Comment: @Dai yeah you are right :)

Comment: I understand how to fix them, I just need the explanation of this behavoir because it is new to me

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I need a setter now when I make `Sedan` inherit from a base class? In my understanding, the `Sedan` will also inherit the getter; So instantiate it with constructor should be ok (just like previous example where it simply implementes the interface).

In C# properties with only a `get` can only be initialized by their own constructor, not a constructor in a subclass. You'll need to add a constructor to `Vehicle` that accepts values for `LicensePlate`, `Speed`, and `Wheels` and then pass those values to the parent class' constructor:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    protected Vehicle( string licensePlate, double speed, int wheels )
    {
        this.LicensePlate = licensePlate;
        this.Speed = speed;  
        this.Wheels = wheels;
    }

    // etc
}

public class Sedan : Vehicle, IAutomobile
{
    public Vehicle( string licensePlate, double speed, int wheels )
        : base( licensePlate, speed, wheels ) 
    {
    }
}
```

> Why is it that it says Sedan does not contain the definition of all these properties when it should just simply inherit from the base class?

`SpeedUp` isn't `Speed`. I think you didn't copy-over all of your code or you need to rebuild your project.

Comment: Sorry about the second error. I have edited my question. It was a mistake because I commented out more  codes than I should.

Answer (score 0):

Get-only properties can only be initialized directly in the class in which they are declared, either in the constructor or directly assigning them where the property members are defined.

The relevant portion of the C# language specification addresses this. The C# spec states

> When a property is specified as an automatically implemented property, a hidden backing field is automatically available for the property, and the accessors are implemented to read from and write to that backing field. **If the auto-property has no set accessor, the backing field is considered readonly (Readonly fields). Just like a readonly field, a getter-only auto-property can also be assigned to in the body of a constructor of the enclosing class.** Such an assignment assigns directly to the readonly backing field of the property.

and it also states

> When a field_declaration includes a readonly modifier, the fields introduced by the declaration are readonly fields. **Direct assignments to readonly fields can only occur as part of that declaration or in an instance constructor or static constructor in the same class.** (A readonly field can be assigned to multiple times in these contexts.) Specifically, direct assignments to a readonly field are permitted only in the following contexts:

> - **In the variable_declarator that introduces the field (by including a variable_initializer in the declaration).**
> - **For an instance field, in the instance constructors of the class that contains the field declaration;** for a static field, in the static constructor of the class that contains the field declaration. These are also the only contexts in which it is valid to pass a readonly field as an out or ref parameter.

So what options do you have?

1. Pass parameters to the base class by calling a base class constructor, and setting your properties there (probably the best approach).
2. Add `protected` to your properties so your subclass can set them. Suboptimal, because now all subclasses can set those properties in a myriad of (possibly inconsistent) ways (e.g. after the class is constructed, mutating state).

Comment: I know interface is different from class, but isn't interface technically the enclosing "class" of these properties in my case? Probably out of topic for this post, but thank you for the elaboration nonetheless

Comment: Unfortunately, no, an interface is not technically the enclosing class, because an interface is not a class. Interfaces, classes, and structs are kinds of *types*. Your comment is definitely not off-topic. Knowing this detail seems pedantic, but it's actually important.

Comment: Also, it took a bit of time to dig through the spec. I knew the answer intuitively as a non-novice (no offense intended). The spec could have been more concisely worded: "get-only properties can only be initialized in the class in which they are declared" rather than reference readonly field rules or the slightly vague "enclosing class". Technical writing can be hard :)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the wrong place the hwole time. It almost feel ike "know how to dig through the spec" is a skill at its own.